# Datos duplicados al agregar una lista a un Array en Angular

Tags: array, angular, typescript, javascript-objeto

estoy consumiendo una API que me devuelve un objeto, que dentro de el hay un array, de este array tengo datos entre ellos ciertos códigos los cuales debo de pasar a sus significados y todo esto se pone en una tabla.

Lo de los códigos lo tengo resuelto, pero el problema esta en lo siguiente:
como necesito poner los datos en una tabla de **angularMaterial** esta me pide que le pase un objeto que contenga la lista a lo cual cree un Array que va a contener las listas.

pero al momento de darle el push.() solo me agrega el ultimo elemento del total de la lista y las multiplica por el total de lista. Al final obtengo 172 listas con el mismo resultado.

```
ArrayCuentas: Array<CuentaForTable> = []; // Array en donde se supone que se almacena las listas

cuenta : CuentaForTable = {} as CuentaForTable; // interfaces donde me pide todo los datos que necesito en la tabla

this.cuentasControllerNg.listCuentaXFechas(beanCuenta).subscribe(res =>{
            this.displayedColumns = ['estado','tipo','de','numero','fecha','vencimiento','importe'];

            for(let i = 0; i < res.lstCuentaBean.length; i++){

                switch (res.lstCuentaBean[i].estado){
                    case 25018: this.cuenta.estado = 'APLICADO';  break;
                    case 25009: this.cuenta.estado = 'CANJEADO';  break;
                    case 25007: this.cuenta.estado = 'PENDIENTE'; break;
                    case 25004: this.cuenta.estado = 'ANULADO';   break;
                    case 25003: this.cuenta.estado = 'CANCELADO'; break;
                    default:    this.cuenta.estado = ''; break;
                }

                switch(res.lstCuentaBean[i].tipo){
                    case 17011: this.cuenta.tipo = 'CUENTA POR COBRAR'; break;
                    case 17012: this.cuenta.tipo = 'CUENTA POR PAGAR';  break;
                    default:    this.cuenta.tipo = ''; break;
                }

                this.cuenta.de = res.lstCuentaBean[i].descripcion;
                this.cuenta.numero = res.lstCuentaBean[i].serie + "-" + res.lstCuentaBean[i].correlativo;
                this.cuenta.fecha = res.lstCuentaBean[i].fecha;
                this.cuenta.vencimiento = res.lstCuentaBean[i].vencimiento;
                this.cuenta.importe = res.lstCuentaBean[i].importe;

                this.ArrayCuentas.push(this.cuenta);
                console.log(this.ArrayCuentas);
            }

        })
```

Imprimo el array para ver y
este es el resultad, a primera vista parece que todo bien pero...
[image: RESULTADO]

abro el primer resultado y me salen los 172 resultados con los mismos datos en todas las filas, todos los demás resultados del Array son lo mismo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, saca el console.log del for. Es un difícil entender lo que pasa, puedes poner una muestra pequeña de los datos que te arroja, en imagen no es muy cómodo leerla, y un ejemplo de el resultado deseado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno ya logre solucionar el problema

1.- Declare el array del tipo de mi interface, fuera de la funcion que realiza la logica

```
cuentas: CuentaForTable[] = [];
```

2.- declare un *const* del tipo de mi interface, y lo inicialice con datos que se van a cambiar dentro del bloque **for**, que es donde recorro cada lista de mi array.

```
for(let i = 0; i < res.lstCuentaBean.length; i++){

                const cuenta : CuentaForTable = {
                    estado: "",
                    tipo: "",
                    de: "",
                    numero: "",
                    fecha: new Date,
                    dias: 0,
                    vencimiento: new Date,
                    importe: 0,
                };

                switch (res.lstCuentaBean[i].estado){
                    case 25018: cuenta.estado = 'APLICADO';  break;
                    case 25009: cuenta.estado = 'CANJEADO';  break;
                    case 25007: cuenta.estado = 'PENDIENTE'; break;
                    case 25004: cuenta.estado = 'ANULADO';   break;
                    case 25003: cuenta.estado = 'CANCELADO'; break;
                    default:    cuenta.estado = ''; break;
                }

                switch(res.lstCuentaBean[i].tipo){
                    case 17011: cuenta.tipo = 'CUENTA POR COBRAR'; break;
                    case 17012: cuenta.tipo = 'CUENTA POR PAGAR';  break;
                    default:    cuenta.tipo = ''; break;
                }

                cuenta.de = res.lstCuentaBean[i].descripcion;
                cuenta.numero = res.lstCuentaBean[i].serie + "-" + res.lstCuentaBean[i].correlativo;
                cuenta.fecha = res.lstCuentaBean[i].fecha;
                cuenta.vencimiento = res.lstCuentaBean[i].vencimiento;
                cuenta.importe = res.lstCuentaBean[i].importe;

                this.cuentas.push(cuenta);
            }
```

3.- Realizo lo que me estan pidiendo para este proble, cambiando los códigos dados por el API a estados que el cliente pueda entender como lo son 'aplicado', 'pendiente', etc

4.- Por ultimo añado mi objeto dentro del array declarado inicialmente, y así obtengo los datos correctos, en este caso como ya es un día diferente me trae 163:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]